# Trying to get some position of JSON using Observables

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Sorry for the question, but I'm newer in Typescript and Ionic and Im a bit confused about how should I proceed.

I have a JSON file with 150 entries based on an interface I'm declared quite simple:

```
export interface ReverseWords {
id: number;
todo: string;
solution: string;}
```

On the other hand, I have a service which reads the json file and returns an Observable of this type (ReverseWords)

```
getReverseWords() {
return this.http.get<ReverseWords>('/assets/data/reves.json');}
```

On .ts file, I call the service and I have all the content of the JSON file. What I want to do (and Im not able to do) is get only one entry based on a random position.

On .ts file:

```
reverseWords: Observable<ReverseWords>; // All the JSON content
reverseWordsSelected: Observable<ReverseWords>; // I would like to get one entry here
```

On ngOnInit():

```
this.reverseWords = this.dataservice.getReverseWords();
```

Everything is fine until here, I've got all the content and I can log it in console. I'm using Observables so I need to subscribe to it to get the information. And I use rxjs/operators pipe and filter to try it, but nothing is showing in the chrome developer console (not even an error).

```
const reverseWordSelectedByPosition = this.reverseWords.pipe(filter(reverseWord => reverseWord.id === randomPosition));
  reverseWordSelectedByPosition.subscribe(console.log);
```

Could anybody help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Other thing I've tested is to do the following in the service:

```
getReverseWords() {
return this.http.get<ReverseWords[]>('/assets/data/reves.json');}
```

And then in the .ts file:

```
reverseWords: Observable<ReverseWords[]>;
```

But I have the same problem.

Finally, the most weird thing is that if I write in the .ts file this simple test:

```
const test = from([
     {
        id: 1,
        todo: 'chapter',
        solution: 'r-e-t-p-a-h-c'
     },
     {
        id: 2,
        todo: 'claustrofobia',
        solution: 'a-i-b-o-f-o-r-t-s-u-a-l-c'
     },
     {
        id: 3,
        todo: 'keyboard',
        solution: 'd-r-a-o-b-y-e-k'
     }
  ]);
```

Everything is fine and I can see on the log only 1 entry if I choose 2, for example.

Any help or advice??
Thanks and sorry for the long approach!!

As TotallyNewb suggested, I show an example of the JSON file, with only 3 entries:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "todo": "chapter",
    "solution": "r-e-t-p-a-h-c"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "todo": "claustrofobia",
    "solution": "a-i-b-o-f-o-r-t-s-u-a-l-c"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "todo": "keyboard",
    "solution": "d-r-a-o-b-y-e-k"
  }
]
```

Comment: It would be easier if you created a stackblitz repro, or at least the sample contents of your .json file. I assume that your .json file contains an array of items. This means that your `http.get` returns an `ReverseWords[]` (or something similar) instead of `ReverseWords`. This means you probably want to use an rxjs `map` operator instead of `filter` and filter items of the array within that. The rxjs `from` works differently - if provided any iterable, it will emit each item from the array separately in a sequence. Your `http.get` returns only one item, which is an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I've edited the message to indicate an example of the JSON file. Yes, the .json file contains an array of items. At the beginning I have a ReverseWords[] in the service and in the .ts file, but then I started to test other ways.
I'll take a look to the map operator and then filter items of the array as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the whole array you can use `map`

```
this.reverseWords.pipe(
    map((items) => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]), // Creates a random index based on the array length
  )
  .subscribe(console.info);
```

If you want to pass the result to `reverseWordsSelected`, you can change it to a `Subject` and pass the value to it from the subscription of `reverseWords` with `.next()`.

You can check out this [stackblitz](https://rxjs-zo4hzc.stackblitz.io) for a working example